# Google Analytics cookie causing error

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am having issues tracking a button click with Google Analytics. When this button is clicked, it’s redirecting to an error page and we see that the cookie parameters are added before the end of the url:

URL:
https://example.com/si/online-shop/#/women?outdoor=A

URL with inserted cookie:
https://example.com/si/online-shop/&__utma=XXX&__utmb=XXX&__utmc=XXX&__utmx=-&__utmz=XXX.utmcsr=(direct)%7Cutmccn=(direct)%7Cutmcmd=(none)&__utmv=-&__utmk=XXX#/women?outdoor=A

I assume, the error is caused by the fact the the URL already contains a question mark and Google automatically adds a question mark to indicate the beginning of the parameters.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that as far as Google is concerned the URL ends after the fragment identifier - that is the way URLs were originally designed to work (i.e. the fragment comes after the query string) before the hashmark came to be widely used in SPAs. So GA inserts its cross domain parameters after the presumed end of the URL and then adds the fragment back. You might try to set the allowHash flag in your linker calls (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiDomainDirectory#_link), but that might break your urls.

Comment: Also you should really consider to upgrade to the current version of the tracking code. This will not only give you more features, it will also be much easier to get help. The version that uses this format for cross domain tracking has been deprecated for so long that not many people will be able to help. Also check if you really need cross domain tracking. Disabling it would be the simplest way to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff!